# Delay of few seconds while using jcarousel framework on mobile device on pageshow() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jcarousel

I'm using an `jQuery` framework - `jcarousel.js` to order some items horizontally on a page in my mobile app builded in `jQuery Mobile`+ `HTML`.

When I navigating to page,first I getting from web service all the images, putting them in a vertical list - `<ul>` dynamically using `JavaScript`
, and calling the script from index this way:

```
   $('#imagesPage').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
        jQuery('#imagesList').jcarousel({visible:2});
   });
```

It works fine in some mobile device's, but in iPhone for example while navigating to that page, it
   done slowly, so you see first the vertical list and after 1-2 sec it changes to horizontal list.

How can I improve it so I wont see the few seconds changing delay from vertical to horizontal and show the page only after list was orginzed currectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should cheat.

**[jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/)** has an init callback function. Let your **`ul`** container be hidden with a little **`css`**:

```
display: block;
```

When **[jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/)** finishes its initialization just show **`ul`** container through **`init`** callback function.

**Working HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/skins/tango/skin.css" />    
        <style>
            .hidden {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>                    
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
        <script>
            $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
                $('#mycarousel').jcarousel({        
                    scroll: 1,
                    initCallback:   carouselInit
                });
            });

            function carouselInit() {
                $('#mycarousel').show();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <h1>Index page</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango hidden">
                    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt=""/></li>
                    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt=""/></li>
                    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt=""/></li>
                    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/77/199481108_4359e6b971_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt=""/></li>
                    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt=""/></li>
                    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/72/199481203_ad4cdcf109_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt=""/></li>
                    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481218_264ce20da0_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt=""/></li>
                    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/69/199481255_fdfe885f87_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt=""/></li>
                    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/60/199480111_87d4cb3e38_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt=""/></li>
                    <li><img src="http://static.flickr.com/70/229228324_08223b70fa_s.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt=""/></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems nice solution! didn't knew that `jcarousel` have `callback`, very good! but I wonder,is there any option to avoid suddenly displaying an organized couresel (after `.show()` function) ? so page would load only after all was done?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is if you initialize everything during the pagebeforecreate event. It is a first page event to trigger during the page initialization: $(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#index', function(){ .....

Comment: When I initializing it using `$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){` I first set a list of images from WS, calling to method `setImages();` , and then calling to `jcarousel` method. As result I am getting horizontal row with images without scroll,they all only opened.Only if I call to `jcarousel` after 1 second it works.I dont want use it with `setTimeout` because in 90% of devices it works fine and I wanted to avoid this delay.

Answer (score 0):

hi I resolved this type of issue in my phonegap based android application by using `setTimeout()` function, Hope it may help you.

Comment: Can you be more specific,what you mean by `setTimout()`, where?

Comment: in my scenario, I intentionally delaying the function calling by using  `setTimeout(myFunction,1500);`
`function myFunction(){`
`$('#carouselDiv').jcarousel();`
`}`